# Are there any differences among USB-C to USB-C cables?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb

I found that I couldn't use the original Apple charging cable to connect my MacBook Pro (2023 M2 Max)
to an external display (Dell U3421WE), but the one that came with the display works fine. Both have USB-C connectors so I assumed they were all equivalent.

- The original Apple cable can charge my MBP quite well. However, it's not projecting my MBP to an external Display.
- The cable with the display is very unstable (sometimes the screen will black out and I have to adjust it a bit to make it work again).

I would like a more reliable cable and wonder what specs should I pay attention to if I want to buy a new cable to drive my display?

Comment: Some cables specified "for charging" are not high-speed for data.

Comment: There is a fantastic write up on USB standards including USB-C (it's changed again with USB 4 and Thunderbolt4.  https://tidbits.com/2021/12/03/usbefuddled-untangling-the-rats-nest-of-usb-c-standards-and-cables/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, USB-C is a connector spec, not a protocol spec.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C)…

> The designation C refers only to the connector's physical configuration or form factor and should not be confused with the connector's specific capabilities, which are designated by its transfer specifications (such as USB 3.2)

There are additional protocol specifications, termed alternate modes, which may or may not be capable in different cables - including DisplayPort, Mobile High-Definition link [MHL] Thunderbolt, HDMI, & VirtualLink.

<sup>Basically, in 7 revisions of the cable spec & as many more in each protocol spec, a virtual rat's nest has been devised. Add to that that not all cables sold are even compliant to any revision & the fun just never stops.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Feeling sad about type-C. Was thinking it would be much better than any of the previous cables.

Comment: I'm often reminded of this… https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png

Answer (score 5):

Your USB-C ports on your Mac and Dell monitor are capable of sending USB data, DisplayPort monitor data and power delivery over a single cable. The specifications, for the USB-C upstream port on your Dell monitor, are given below.

| USB speed | Monitor Resolution | Power Delivery |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 Gb/s (USB 3.2 Gen 1) | 4K@60 Hz (DP 1.4) | 90 Watts |

A cable, which meets USB 3.2 specifications, will have 4 high speed data lanes. (A lane is a pair of wires). When connected between the proper USB-C ports on the Mac and monitor, two lanes will be used to transmit USB data and the other two lanes will be used two transmit DisplayPort data. According to the USB 3.2 specifications, the highest speed USB can operate at under this configuration is 10 Gb/s. Your Mac is capable of this 10 Gb/s USB speed, but the Dell monitor is only capable of 5 Gb/s. So purchasing a cable rated at 5 Gb/s should work for USB data. However the 10 Gb/s cables are about the same price and a 10 Gb/s cable would help insure the quality of the DisplayPort data transmission.

An example cable would be the following from [StarTech](https://www.amazon.com/stores/StarTech/page/6C0E5AEF-F9E4-4E55-9983-4D6289F918C5?ref_=ast_bln).

- [3ft (1m) USB C Cable 10Gbps - USB-IF Certified USB-C Cable - USB 3.1/3.2 Gen 2 Type-C Cable - 100W (5A) Power Delivery Charging, DP Alt Mode - USB C to C Cord - Charge & Sync (USB31CCV1M)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09J9BXFFD)

---

**Note:** The USB 3.2 specification is included in the Thunderbolt 3 specification and the Thunderbolt 3 specification is included in the Thunderbolt 4 specification. This allows cable descriptions to advertise Thunderbolt compatibility even when actual cable is only capable of transmitting data USB 3.2 speeds and not at the higher speeds of Thunderbolt 3 and 4. You should check the specifications of the cable before purchasing.

---

### References

- [Dell UltraSharp 34 Curved USB-C Hub Monitor - U3421WE
  User’s Guide](https://dl.dell.com/content/manual29681286-dell-u3421we-monitor-user-s-guide.pdf?language=en-us)

Answer (score 1):

The best possible video connection in you specific situation (assuming a. you have the open port and b. you aren't using the monitor as a USB hub) is to get a USB-C -> Display Port 1.2 (or higher) cable and use the Display Port input on the monitor. (Rather than 5 Gb/s that the monitors USB tops out at, you should get over 8Gb/s or over 17Gb/s in HBR2 mode.

Beyond that... you want to pay close attention to the USB Spec for cables. USB 3.1 Gen 2 has a max throughput rate of 10 Gb/s and is probably the minimum you want for anything but charging. Ideally, you would look for a USB 4 Cable which is capable of 40 Gb/s. While both of these exceed your monitors USB specs, it provides more flexibility for other devices.

To get the best possible connection in most situations you may want to go with a Thunderbolt 4 cable. This is backwards compatible with TB3 and USB 3-4, so whatever device you are connecting to, you will get the best connection that your Mac is currently capable of (assuming a USB-C type connection on both ends).

One thing to keep in mind with TB4 cables is that there are both active and passive cables. Passive is fine (and less expensive) cables that are ~3ft or shorter, longer than that you may want active cables which are quite bit more expensive since they have there own embedded circuits to maintain the integrity of data over a longer cable.

Answer (score -1):

There are many kinds of USB-C cables.  To distinguish which is which should take no more than a look at the iconography on the ends of the cables.  That is what should happen but even that isn't enough because of the complexities of the USB-C specification and because not everyone follows the specification to the letter.

One big distinction between cable types is being active or passive.  Passive cables have no electronics in the data path and so will carry any protocol placed on them, the only real limit is that some protocols take more bandwidth than others and the bandwidth of passive cables is largely dictated by their length.  There will be exceptions but generally 2 meter cables support only USB 2.0, 1 meter cables support 20 Gbps, and 3/4 meter cables support 40 Gbps.  A shorter cable may support only USB 2.0 speeds because it lacks the "super speed" wires required for greater bandwidth, and even if the wires are present in the cable the quality of the wires might not be up to spec for greater bandwidth.

Passive USB-C cables that would be capable of supporting DisplayPort would likely be marked with the stylized "SS" (for "super speed") logo, and perhaps also have a number 5, 10, or 20 to indicate the maximum supported data rate in Gbps.  This is for USB speeds so with protocols other than USB the data rate may be higher.  Newer USB-C cables using the newer USB4 iconography will have a stylized number 20 or 40 instead of the "SS" to indicate supported bandwidth, a number more closely approximating maximum supported data rates for other protocols for reasons that I won't go into right now.

A passive USB-C cable that is marked as supporting USB at 10, 20, or 40 Gbps should work fine for a DisplayPort display but that might mean using a cable that is unacceptably short.  Even then with a lower quality cable there may be limits on supported resolution and refresh rates.

Active USB-C cables will have electronics in them to pass data along so the electronics have to understand the protocol in order to work, which means needing to take greater care in selecting cables.  How can someone tell a passive cable from an active one?  The price of the cable may be one indicator, passive cables are simpler and so should cost less.  Given how there are plenty of places selling cheap cables at inflated prices this is hardly a sure thing.

Active cables, like passive cables, should have markings on the cable ends to indicate supported protocols.  I have yet to see a USB-C cable marked for DisplayPort but that doesn't mean they don't exist.  The Thunderbolt specification requires backward compatibility with DisplayPort so a Thunderbolt cable should work to connect a DisplayPort display to a computer but because of how the specifications changed over time I am uncertain on how far this compatibility goes.

Because of the abundance of poorly made cables yet on the market, and DisplayPort over USB-C still being relatively new, it may be difficult to find a new cable that does any better than what you have.  The intent of USB-C supporting so many different protocols, at least in the beginning, was to allow for a dock to break out the different protocols from the USB-C port (a conveniently small port) to feed the various (and full sized) ports for different devices.  For this reason it may be to your benefit to seek out a dock of some sort to feed power into your MacBook and video into your display by separate cables.  A dock and two cables may end up costing less than a single USB-C cable built to the required specifications to do as you wish reliably.

A quick search for a DisplayPort cable with USB-C connectors on both ends came up empty.  As I mentioned before that doesn't mean they don't exist, only that they are rare.  A Thunderbolt cable should work but if taking that route it may be lower cost and easier to find a dock and set of cables to do the same thing.  A short passive Thunderbolt cable will be easy enough to find, and be inexpensive, but my guess is the cable you have is coming loose from being too short.

Comment: Active USB cables have electronic *repeaters* built in that is designed  to extend the distance the signal can travel; in other words, use a longer cable.  There is no reason for this “big distinction”.

Comment: Different active USB-C cables will be built to support different protocols.  An active USB 3.x cable will not necessarily support DisplayPort.  It might but that is not always true.  It depends on how it is built.  Also, just because a cable is longer does not mean it is active.  One short interpretation of my long explanation above is to pay attention to the markings on the cable, if it has a DisplayPort or Thunderbolt icon then it should work.  Because it is not always that simple I went into greater detail.

Comment: I stopped reading after this sentence:  *Different active USB-C cables will be built to support different protocols.*. The question is ***not** about active versus passive.  USB-C has nothing to do with protocols.  “C” is the connector type; more commonly referred to as Type-C.  You don’t send a *protocol* down a cable; you send *electrical signaling*.  To be a proper USB-C cable, it must have all the required signaling including power and DP.  What you’ve written here is confusing at best.

Comment: I'll give examples of two active USB-C cables, one supports Thunderbolt and the other does not. Uni-directional DP and USB cable: https://www.cablematters.com/pc-1136-124-full-feature-active-usb-c-cable-with-10-gbps-data-4k-video-and-pd-charging-support.aspx  Bi-directional cable supporting USB, DP, and Thunderbolt: https://www.cablematters.com/pc-1516-124-20gbps-active-usb4-cable-5m.aspx  The uni-directional cable costs half as much as the bi-directional cable but both are active cables with USB-C connectors on both ends.  Not all active USB-C cables are built to support all USB-C protocols.

Comment: The product examples in my comment above are not endorsements of any kind, they are merely examples I could find quickly.  The examples given are merely to illustrate that not all active cables are equal, some support protocols that others do not.